# Django: output textfile to be proceeded

Tags: python, django, latex, tex

i have a small django application that i use to manage my patients data ( i am a doctor with an intermediate level in python/django)
I used LaTeX to output my reports *via* a view function like that

```
def consultation_pdf(request, pk2, pk1):
    entry = Consultation.objects.get(pk=pk2)
    source = Patient.objects.get(pk=pk1)
#    context = Context({ 'consultation': entry, 'patient': source })
    context = dict({'consultation': entry, 'patient': source})
    template = get_template('clinic/consultation.tex')
    rendered_tpl = template.render(context, request).encode('utf-8')
# Python3 only. For python2 check out the docs!
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        # Create subprocess, supress output with PIPE and
        # run latex twice to generate the TOC properly.
        # Finally read the generated pdf.
        for i in range(2):
            process = Popen(
                                           ['xelatex', '-output-directory', tempdir],
                                           stdin=PIPE,
                                           stdout=PIPE,
                                          )
        process.communicate(rendered_tpl)
        with open(os.path.join(tempdir, 'texput.pdf'), 'rb') as f:
            pdf = f.read()
r = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
r.write(pdf)
return r
```

Now i need to switch to [ConTeXT](https://www.contextgarden.org) since it fills more my needs.

The biggest problem so far is that ConTeXT needs both the `source` file **and** the `pdf` to be saved on the disk, and not simply piping `stdin` and `stdout` , respectively.

How could i manage to complete this task? so far the only workaround i've found is to generate a `tex` file then run it manually.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why is this a problem?  You can save the input file to disk before you call out to context.  I'm not sure of how the command line for context works, but this is how you would save the file:

```
import uuid
import os

def consultation_pdf(request, pk2, pk1):
    entry = Consultation.objects.get(pk=pk2)
    source = Patient.objects.get(pk=pk1)
    #    context = Context({ 'consultation': entry, 'patient': source })
    context = dict({'consultation': entry, 'patient': source})
    template = get_template('clinic/consultation.tex')
    rendered_tpl = template.render(context, request)
    # save the file to disk
    filename = uuid.uuid4()
    # Python3 only. For python2 check out the docs!
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        filename = os.path.join(tempdir, filename.hex)
        with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8') as infile:
            infile.write(rendered_tpl)
        # Create subprocess, supress output with PIPE and
        # run latex twice to generate the TOC properly.
        # Finally read the generated pdf.
        for i in range(2):
            process = Popen(
                ['context', filename, '-output-directory', 
                  tempdir],
                stdin=PIPE,
                stdout=PIPE,)
        process.communicate(rendered_tpl)
        with open(os.path.join(tempdir, 'texput.pdf'), 'rb') as f:
            pdf = f.read()
            r = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
            r.write(pdf)
            return r
```

Comment: i have an error message `join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'UUID'`

Comment: i did convert `filename` into `str(filename) in line **15**, now i got this `write() argument must be a str not a byte`

Comment: My bad:  fixes incorporated above.  Remove the `encode` from the render template, and then use `.hex` with the uuid to convert it to an `str`.

Comment: i finally managed to output a pdf, so far i have 2 issues: 1. django throws an error 2. the generated pdf is located on the root of my project, i need to either download the file as an attachement or to save it in a spacified folder , say `media/{patient.slug}/{consutation.date}/`. i will fix my view function and mark the topic as answered. thank you a lot!